# Scatter/Gather with timeout in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to use RxJava and AsyncHttpClient to call multiple web services in parallel and then process the results of each one. I need to limit the amount of time spent waiting for the services to return. The constraint I'm having trouble with is how to deal with the services that don't finish in time. I've limited the network time in the AsyncHttpRequest itself, and in the Single.Merge() with take(), but how do I determine which Single did not return because they did not complete before the take() expired? Here is some code:

```
public List<Single<MyResponse>> fetchS(List<MyRequest> requestlist, final AsyncHttpClient ahc) {
        List<Single<MyResponse>> ret =
            requestlist.stream().map(req -> Single.fromCompletionStage(convert(req, ahc))).collect(
                Collectors.toList());
        return ret;
    }

var responsesS = new FetcherImpl().fetchS(requests, ahc);

Single<List<MyResponse>> merged =
           Single.merge(responsesS).take(500,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).toList();

merged.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe( list -> { process(list);})
```

Basically, how do I deal with the items that did not finish in the 500ms time limit of take()?

TIA

Comment: How do ou want to handle a request, which time-outs? Should all running requests be cancelled or do you want to handle each failed request (e.g. provide default value)?

Comment: Every request should be allowed to run until either it hits its network timeout or the take() expirers. I need to be able to distinguish all three cases, succes, timeout, take limit, for each one, no default needed

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
class MyResponse {
            String reponse;
            Throwable error;
        }

        List<Single<MyOriginalResponse>> singles =
                new ArrayList(Single.defer(() -> Single.just(new MyOriginalResponse()))
                        .timeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                        .map(myResponse -> new MyResponse(myResponse))
                        .onErrorReturn(throwable -> MyResponse(throwable)));
```

Basically you have a wrapper class that contains either a response or a throwable. There are solutions out there like https://github.com/eleventigers/rxeither that would give you a `Either<Throwable, MyOriginalResponse>` and then from there you can continue your flow depending on what you get.

Hope it helps